# Android Handling changing of orientation. app crash points on changing image using glide

Tags: android, logcat, android-glide

Details:
I am changing image from drawable using Glide. When I changed orientation into landscape it gives me a logcat error pointing to method I use for changing my image with Glide.

Code snippet:

```
private void changeDice1(int drawable) {
    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(drawable)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(ivDice1);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Logcat error:

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: in a function that is also called inside onCreate.

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Glide` loads image asynchronously. So if you change the orientation of your device, it may happen that, the reference context is changed and an exception is thrown. So modify your function like this using a `try-catch` block.

```
private void changeDice1(int drawable) {
    try{
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load(drawable)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(ivDice1);
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Now call the function again in `onConfigurationChanged`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    changeDice1(R.drawable.your_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Glide.clear()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clear(com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target)) to cancel a load.

However, that exception occurs when you try to start a new load after your activity has been destroyed. Are you starting to load images after fetching some data asynchronously? If so you probably want to cancel your async fetch when your activity is stopped or at least ignore the result if the fetch finishes and your activity is destroyed.

see this issue for more information: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/975